# Check if item is like one in another table

Tags: sql

How to check if item is LIKE or CONTAINS the one in another table ?

I have this SQL query where I want to count total number of hosts for each new product but only in case if that product exists in the `old_products` table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name,COUNT (DISTINCT host) AS total_number
FROM new_products
WHERE name IN (SELECT productname FROM old_products)
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY total_number DESC;
```

The problem is that in my case this doesn't work because in the table `new_products` the version is also noted but in table `old_products` it is not.

### EXAMPLE

**new_products**

```
name
----
Nmap 7.70
Internet Explorer 10
Internet Explorer 11
```

**old_products**

```
productname
----
Nmap
Internet Explorer
```

How should I build the query to match `Internet Explorer 10` in `new_products` with `Internet Explorer` in `old_products` ?

So instead of `IN` I should have something like `LIKE IN` - how to do that ?

Thanks.

Comment: No need to do `SELECT DISTINCT` here, since the `GROUP BY` returns no duplicates.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
SELECT np.NAME, np.PRODUCTNAME
  FROM NEW_PRODUCTS np
  CROSS JOIN OLD_PRODUCTS op
    WHERE
             CHARINDEX(op.name, np.name) > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

`LIKE` will do the job just fine:

```
SELECT NAME, PRODUCTNAME
  FROM NEW_PRODUCTS np
  CROSS JOIN OLD_PRODUCTS op
  WHERE np.NAME LIKE '%' || op.PRODUCTNAME || '%' OR
        op.PRODUCTNAME LIKE '%' || np.NAME || '%'
```

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0a713e77def9ad0c926c617bf5217015)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EXISTS`:

```
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM old_products op
              WHERE new_products.name LIKE op.product_name || '%'
             )
```

This uses the standard operator for string concatenation.  You haven't specified the database and not all databases support `||`.  For instance, in SQL Server, the operator is `+`.

For the overall query:

```
SELECT np.name, COUNT(DISTINCT host) AS total_number
FROM new_products np
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM old_products op
              WHERE np.name LIKE op.product_name || '%'
             )
GROUP BY np.name
ORDER BY total_number DESC;
```

Note that this removes the redundant `DISTINCT` and introduces table aliases and qualified column names.